# MySQL: where is tmpdir? There are no files in /tmp

Tags: mysql, tmp

I'm running a large query, and I'm getting the following error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.InternalError: (3, "Error writing file '/tmp/MYo8b3Z4' (Errcode: 28)")
```

This means I'm running out of disk space in my tmpdir which is evidently /tmp.
Now, I want to make sure that this is indeed the problem. So I run the query, and constantly monitor the contents of /tmp. But as the query is executing, the contents of /tmp do not change at all. No new files, no existing files changing size.

What does this mean? Is my tmpdir somewhere else?

( I do have a line in my.cnf that reads `tmpdir = /tmp` )

Answer (score 0):

The temporary files will be deleted after errors and similar events occurs.

But you can view the temporary files during the query, some times MySQL stores the temporary files in the same database path and their files begins with `#`.

Comment: Check your data folder /.../mysql/your_database_name/